# C++ Passing template's constructor value in template's parameter

Tags: c++, templates, initialization

I am trying to pass a class as a template parameter. But this class has only one mandatory constructor where we have to pass an integer value. So I am trying to find a way to initialize the template's constructor parameter.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class F>
class Class1 {
public:
    int i = 0;
    F f;
    Class1() { i = f.u; }
};

class Class2 {
public:
    int u = 5;
    Class2(int j) { u = j; }
};

int main() {
    Class1 <Class2>c;
    std::cout << c.i << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, this gives me an error "Class2 no appropriate default constructor available". Saying that I want to pass different classes with constructors that does not have the same number of parameters in Class1's template , is there a way to initialize the template's constructor? I'm looking for something like Class1 c;

Comment: What is the purpose of `Class1`? At the moment it looks like it is just wrapping a `F` instance and then holding another copy of one of its data members, which seems very pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class1 c;` will not be possible as a general solution. If different `F`s will have different constructors, you need to specify what to pass to that constructor somewhere.

One way that seems to make sense would be to forward the arguments from `Class1`s constructor to `F`.

If `F` has a default constructor, you will be able to construct `Class1` without passing anything.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class F>
class Class1 {
public:
    int i = 0;
    F f;
    template <typename... Args>
    Class1(Args&&... args) : f(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { i = f.u; }
};

class Class2 {
public:
    int u = 5;
    Class2(int j) { u = j; }
    Class2() = default;
};

int main() {
    Class1<Class2> c(10);
    Class1<Class2> c2;
    std::cout << c.i << " " << c2.i << std::endl;
}
```